# Disable InfoWindow in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

Hi do you disable Google infoWindow on my google maps as you can see by visiting http://harpers.everythingcreative.co.uk/contact the info window looks odd and displays the incorrect address.

```
    // ---------- Geolocation ----------    
function fallback() {
            var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.43255949795703, -0.461750328540802),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map_Canvas"),
            myOptions);

            var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.43255949795703, -0.461750328540802);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerPos,
            map: map,
            title: "The Harpers Hairdressing"
            });
            }

   function initGeolocation() 
    { 
           if(navigator.geolocation) 
            { 
              // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks 
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail ); 
            } 
        else 
            { 
              fallback()
               } 
    } 
    var directionDisplay; 
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
    var map; 
    function success(position) { 
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
      coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
position.coords.longitude); 
      var myOptions = { 
        zoom:12, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
        center: coords 
      } 
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map_Canvas"), 
myOptions); 
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      calcRoute();
    } 
    function calcRoute() { 
      var start = coords; 
      var end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.43255949795703, -0.461750328540802); 
      var request = { 
        origin:start, 
        destination: "3 Fir Tree Place, Church Road, Ashford, Middlesex, TW15 2PH",
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      }; 
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(result); 
        } 
      }); 
    } 
        function fail() 
        { 

           fallback();

}
```

As you can see the fallback is a simple marker that doesn't display and info window but the Directions does.

Answer (score 1):

On your DirectionsRenderer object you can pass in a DirectionsRendererOptions struct of options.  Within that is a markerOptions value, which you should be able to use to disassociate the marker from the map.

Something like this might work:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  markerOptions : {
        map: null,  //  you probably would only need 1 or the other of these two values
        visible: false
  }
});
```

Comment: That half fixes it as it hides the markers completely but not the infoWindow

Answer (score 1):

use suppressInfoWindows:true within the layer's option:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: {
            enabled: false
        },
        options: {
            suppressInfoWindows:true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using duncan's fix i just used the clickable:false option and it seemed to do the trick, thank you very much!

```
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        markerOptions : {
            visible: true,
            clickable: false
        }
  });
```